# SumatraPDF inverse search for RNW files

Tags: texstudio, knitr, sumatrapdf, rnw

I'm using TexStudio to edit my `rnw` files. I setup an inverse search from SumatraPDF to TexStudio using [THIS](http://alperyazar.blogspot.com/2014/09/en-create-search-link-between-texstudio.html) (verbatim) which is a renewed version of [THIS](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/texstudio-sumatrapdf/). When I double click a text in SumatraPDF it opens the `tex` file and shows the correct text. But I want it to open the `rnw` file and find the correct text there. How can I do that?

I'm using following command in SumatraPDF:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\texstudio.exe" "%f" -line %l
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Problem:** This is neiter an issue of TeXstudio nor of Sumatra PDF. Instead it's a result of the combination of Synctex and the build chain is `rnw -> tex -> pdf`. Synctex is originally designed to provide a connection between the tex file and the pdf. It does not know anything about the rnw.

**Towards a Solution:** I'm not an R user and therefore have no ready solution. However the package *patchDVI* seems to be the thing to look for. Additionally, this description may help: http://starlinq.livejournal.com/5762.html

Comment: Thanks for restating the problem in a correct way. The link you've provided is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.